# call second I:EventTrigger on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, interaction, eventtrigger

I have a `CustomButton` with two `I:EventTrigger`. The first Interaction is calling a method (SubmitResult) and the second one (ClosePopupAction) should only be called on a result of the first one. My implementation with the `IsEnabled` Property does not work.

#### XAML

```
<Controls:CustomButton>
    <I:Interaction.Triggers>
        <I:EventTrigger EventName="CustomClick">
            <Ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" MethodName="SubmitData"/>
        </I:EventTrigger>
        <I:EventTrigger EventName="CustomClick">
            <Actions:ClosePopupAction IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=InvokeClose, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </I:EventTrigger>
    </I:Interaction.Triggers>
</Controls:CustomButton>
```

#### C# Code

```
public bool InvokeClose
{
    get { return _InvokeClose; }
    set
    {
        if (_InvokeClose == value) return;
        _InvokeClose = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private bool _InvokeClose;

public void SubmitData()
{
    InvokeClose = true;
}
```

#### Action

```
public class ClosePopupAction:TargetedTriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        HtChildWindow window = FindChildWindow(AssociatedObject);
        window?.Close();
    }

    private HtChildWindow FindChildWindow(DependencyObject element)
    {
        IAttachedObject attachedObject = element as IAttachedObject;
        if(attachedObject != null)
            return FindChildWindow(attachedObject.AssociatedObject);

        HtChildWindow childWindow = element as HtChildWindow;
        return childWindow ?? FindChildWindow(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element));
    }
}
```

If i set `InvokeClose` to `true` as initalValue, it works like expected.

Comment: Do you want the second one to work? Don't you have to pass the target popup as well to it?

If ClosePopupAction is a custom Action, can we see your code for it?

Comment: Have added the action. I'm writing some data to a db in the SubmitData() method. And if all is successfull, I want to close this popup. I have already a solution. (I made an `EventHandler` and listen via `I:EventTrigger EventName="InvokeClose" SourceObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">` for the event. But I also want another solution. The ClosePopupAction should only be called, if the "InvokeClose" bool is true.)

Comment: But if the first action is the one thats supposed to set InvokeClose to True,
Then you will have to click a second time for the second Action(which will now be Enabled) to work. No?

Comment: Right, but then the first action is triggered again and I would do it with only one click.

Comment: What, how? and doesn't it seem redundant? Something seems off to me.
I would have expected that the first action(alone) would invoke a command from the ViewModel. There it would go to the service managing your windows and close the one you need to...

Comment: It is fireing both Methods (CallMethodAction; ClosePopupAction) with one click. BUT in the second Method (ClosePopupAction) the bool (InvokeClose) is still false and the action won't get fired! If i click again, both are fired again and the bool is true from the last "round" and the action get's fired.

Comment: Of course, that is what I guessed was happening, and its also logical.
Allow me to reiterate my earlier comment.
Something in the design here is wrong. Since data is involved with your business logic I would recommend you move everything to a ViewModel that will be the DataContext of this View. In it  build a command that your action on the Button will raise. In its execution you should place all conditions and subsequent actions based on these conditions.